# User opens up an HTML document in IE and sees the HTML?

Tags: html

I'm generating an HTML doc through my system, and when the user opens up the doc in IE, they see the actual html and javasctipt- not the rendered HTML.

Why would that happen?

Comment: without knowing more, I'd have to guess that it's being served with an incorrect mime type.

Comment: is it working in other browser???

Comment: those users only have IE installed, so i can't test on other browsers. What mime type should i be using? Here's what my api says "Indicates how the attachment should be rendered. Valid values are any mime type/subtype. The default value is 'text'. "

Comment: would text/html  do it?

Comment: text/html is correct for HTML. But how are you sending the document? Via HTTP, or some other way?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela text/html worked. I'm not sure how the UI implements sending email.. what's the impact? is that something that i need to consider?

Answer (score 2):

> Why would that happen?

If it is saved with any other format other than `.htm` or `.html`

and in extreme cases: If your html is escaped by HTML entities.